# Spring Boot 1.4 Unit Test Hibernate Validation WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am trying to perform  a unit test in Spring Boot 1.4 to test my validation returns a 400 on an invalid query string parameter.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class ExampleController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/example", method = GET)
    public Response getExample(
            @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) @Valid @Pattern(regexp = MY_REGEX) String segmentsRequest {

        // Stuff here
    }

}
```

**Exception Handler**

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    // 400 - Bad Request
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void constrainViolationHandle(HttpServletRequest request, ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        logger.error("Error Bad Request (400)");
    }

}
```

**Context**

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider())
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    final MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ExampleController.class)
public class ExampleControllerTest {

    private static final String EMPTY = "";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        // Perform Request
        ResultActions response = this.mvc.perform(
            get("/example").param("userId", "invalid")
        );

        // Assert Result
        response.andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().string(EMPTY));
    }

}
```

However when I run my test I get a `200` not a `400`. The validation is not performed when I am running as an Application just not as a test.

I believe it may be due to it not picking up the two validation beans when performing the test? 
This validation works

Answer (score 2):

`@WebMvcTest` annotation you are using is Spring Boot wrapper on top of so called standalone MockMvc configuration. This MockMvc feature tests standalone controller without any other beans.

To be able to test wider web configuration you need to use [web application setup](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server-setup-options):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("my-servlet-context.xml")
public class MyWebTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    // ...

}
```

But notice that such web application setup doesn't pick up all the beans. For example you would need to explicitly register Servler filters or Spring Security. But I believe validation should be included.